# SQLite3 inconsistency mistake in between function

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am using the SQLite3 database with Python and already inserted the data via a csv import. While I was playing around with it to get used to the database and trying various commands, I realised that there has to be a mistake somewhere.

The mistake is visible in the result of the last line:

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect('databaseTest.db')
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT avg(LOAN_AMOUNT) FROM loans")
print(cur.fetchone())            # Result: 832.23€

cur.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM loans WHERE LOAN_AMOUNT BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000")
print(cur.fetchone())            # Result: 414114

cur.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM loans WHERE LOAN_AMOUNT BETWEEN 500 AND 2000")
print(cur.fetchone())            # Result: 0
```

As you can see the error happens in the last statement where it says that there are 0 loans with an amount between 500 and 2000 (while there are 414114 loans with an amount between 1000 and 2000).

Does anyone have an idea what I did wrong? I am very new to coding and working with databases, so it might as well be a very simple, stupid mistake. I checked the data in the database which seem to be all fine.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What is the data type of the LOAN_AMOUNT column in your table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not answer the question for the column's data type, I'm gonna have to base my answer on the assumption that it is TEXT. At least my q&d tests  with TEXT showed exactly the behavior you describe in the question.

The comparison of the string is done via one-to-one matching.
The first character of 500 as a string has a bigger value than the first character of 2000 as a string. Very simplified, your condition reads like `value greater than 5 and less than 2`.

```
print("500" > "2000") # True!!!!
print(500 > 2000)     # False
```